# Tourist spots on Munich airport terminal B

Tags: germany, airports, munich

Is there any tourist spot worth watching at Munich airport terminal B?

Comment: Somewhere to watch tourists? Somewhere to do fun things as a tourist? Somewhere to see planes? Other?

Comment: There are seasonal events in the main terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to leave the building and go to the [Visitor's Park](http://munich-airport.de/en/consumer/erlebnis/besucherpark/index.jsp) you could visit the [Visitor's terrace](http://munich-airport.de/en/consumer/erlebnis/besucherterr/index.jsp) which offers a great view to the apron and currently the construction site of terminal 2's new satellite building. The terrace is located outside the secure area. The entrance is located in the upper floor of the public area of the terminal.

[image: Visitor's terrace]

<sup>Source: flickr user [Curimedia | P H O T O G R A P H Y](https://www.flickr.com/photos/curimedia/10677066045/in/photolist-nMiHS1-fLeod6-e9fFWm-hgHWtc-hguKKB), [CC-BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/).</sup>